# Need help creating a Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, project, project-management, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have to create a Use Case Diagram for a project management software. What I need to take into account is which are the actors working with the software and which are the important activities.

That's how I made it:

[image]

Is it correct, did I choose the actors and activities properly and is there anything else that needs to be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks :

- the arrow of your extend is very probably on the wrong side, currently *set a priority* is extended by *set assignments*. The notation is `extended UC <--<<extend>>-- extending UC`, and it is *extend* rather than *extend**s***
- *project manager* and *project member* cannot *login*, they already login to be a manager or a member, furthermore the login does not have enough added value to be an (interesting) use case, better to remove it
- *receive a message* is not an UC or is wrongly named, a *project member* decides to read a message but the reception of the message is done by the mailbox subsystem without stimulus from the member. An other problem is its inclusion by the UC *add project members*, that one can include *send message* but not *receive message* nor *read message* in case you rename it
- globally you have several UC using plural, like *send messages*, *attach files* etc, so it seems not possible to send *one* message etc, better to name them not using plural or may be placing *s* between parenthesis ?
- except the problematic *receive a message* the included UCs are included by only one UC and never directly activated by an actor, for me these UCs are useless then and their behavior directly placed in the including UC. An UC is not just a name in an ellipsis, an UC must have an associated description
- very probably a *project manager* can read message and can *process project information*, in that case *project manager* inherits *project member*
- being on the right *project member* seems to be a secondary actor, this is a very common notation even not part of the standard, better to place it on the left, out of the fact very probably *project manager* inherits *project member*

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I'll make the necessary corrections. Regarding project member being on the left side, it should also be on top and project manager below it since project manager inherits project member, right? And what about project sponsor, should I leave it as it is and are there other actors that I could be missing (maybe mail system or anything else)?

Comment: @jay252 you can place the inheriting and inherited actors where you want, the arrow is not necessary from top to bottom nor the reverse, place actors and corresponding UCs in order to have a readable diagram. Supposing *to pay license fees* part of the studied system that UC and associated actor are ok as they are. About possible missing actor and UC only you can know because only you knows what the system does ;-)